# Escape ( ' ) in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am using return url to facebook  in ROR as

```
  <fb:login-button length="long" onlogin='location.href = "<%= check_url %>?id=<%= @a %>"' scope="publish_stream" >Post to my Wall</fb:login-button>
```

here @a is dynamic variable, It is large string more than 10 character.
eg:-

```
case 1:- @a= You have the power to influence all with whom you come in contact. 
case 2:- @=You'll never be the man your mother was!
```

case 1 is Working 
But case 2 is not because of (') .How to escape this (').

Comment: Did you try to escape using `\'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CGI::escape()` to URL encode the variable before passing as a parameter to the url like this: `'location.href = "<%= check_url %>?id=<%= CGI::escape(@a) %>"'`